# How to reset a ESPurna LED bulb?

Tags: smart-lights

I have a LED smart bulb (probably a [ESP8255 based one](https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna/wiki/Hardware-AI-Thinker-AI-Light)) flashed with [ESPurna](https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna). It was configured to connect to my WiFi network and it does, but unfortunately I forgot the password to connect to it (it presents a Basic Authentication login popup).

[I have hope](https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna/issues/87) that a hard reset would bring it back to factory settings but I do not know how to perform that hard reset.

I tried to switch it on (for 4-5 seconds) and off a few times, as read somewhere but it did not do the trick.

**Is there a standard (or at least expected) way to shortcut some PINs in order to simulate a "reset button press"?** (I really, really would like to avoid reflashing it because of the tricky soldering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching it on and off probably won't help as the configuration is probably saved into non-volatile memory. You do not want to reconfigure your device after every blackout or such.

Your other chanse would be the hard reset feature added in release 1.6.7 but that would require a button and as per the [espurna/config/hardware.h](https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna/blob/dev/code/espurna/config/hardware.h) file, the AI-Thinker AI Light does not have a button defined by default.

```c
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// AI Thinker
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#elif defined(AITHINKER_AI_LIGHT)

    // Info
    #define MANUFACTURER        "AITHINKER"
    #define DEVICE              "AI_LIGHT"
    #define RELAY_PROVIDER      RELAY_PROVIDER_LIGHT
    #define LIGHT_PROVIDER      LIGHT_PROVIDER_MY92XX
    #define DUMMY_RELAY_COUNT   1

    // Light
    #define LIGHT_CHANNELS      4
    #define MY92XX_MODEL        MY92XX_MODEL_MY9291
    #define MY92XX_CHIPS        1
    #define MY92XX_DI_PIN       13
    #define MY92XX_DCKI_PIN     15
    #define MY92XX_COMMAND      MY92XX_COMMAND_DEFAULT
    #define MY92XX_MAPPING      0, 1, 2, 3
```

There is no such thing on the [schematic](http://wiki.jackslab.org/Noduino_OpenLight#Schemmatics) either.

All in all you will need a re-flash, either to reset the configuration or to upload a new firmware with a button defined on one of the free GPIOs of the ESP.

Comment: Switching on and off several times within quick succession (allowing the light to turn on before switching off) is indeed the way some bulbs are designed to reset.

Comment: @multithr3at3d With what firmware?

Comment: not sure about firmware, but I am referring to Magic Home/Flux LED bulbs I believe

Comment: I ended up reflashing. As for the switch on/off sequence to reset the bulb - I found several mentions on Internet (such as https://www.cnet.com/news/manually-reset-smart-led-light-bulbs/)